# Libreoffice 4.2.7.2 bug: will it be an upgrade to 4.3 soon?

Tags: libreoffice

I got this bug in Libreoffice today, was advised to upgrade to LO 4.3, will an official upgrade for Ubuntu 14.04 be available soon?
http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/43767/calc-deleted-several-foreign-sheet-name-references/

Comment: You should probably open a bug on launchpad, and then linking it to the upstream; after that a SRU (stable release update) can be asked. If you open the bug, please post the link here.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a bit newbie to Linux, I wouldn't know how to do all that, plus my usage of Libreoffice is just personal and nothing critical. I'm sure there will be someone more knowledgeable on the procedure and also more wary of losing all the formulas in an important Calc worksheet as to do it him/herself. I just wanted to shout it out for those interested to know.